# volcar datos en grilla seleccionando desde dropdownList

Tags: c#, gridview, dropdownlist

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un proyecto donde en un dropdownlist tengo que cargarlo con los rucs de las farmaceuticas, y cuando selecciono un ruc , aparezca la informacion de todos los medicamentos en una gridview, cree los procedimientos para ello y lo unico que logro es que me muestre los rucs en el drop, la grilla ni aparece, cual puede ser el problema? me podrian orientar ? gracias.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<Farmaceutica> Lista = LogicaFarmaceutica.ListarFarm();
            if (Lista != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    drplistarfarma.DataSource = Lista;
                    drplistarfarma.DataTextField = "ruc";
                    drplistarfarma.DataValueField = "ruc";
                    drplistarfarma.DataBind();




                }
                catch
                {
                    lblerror.Text = "Error en grilla";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Medicamentos M = null;
            string ruc = drplistarfarma.SelectedValue;
            int numero = Convert.ToInt32(Gvmedicamentos.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
            Session["medi"] = LogicaMedicamento.ListarFarma(M.Farmacia);
            Gvmedicamentos.DataSource = Session["medi"];
            Gvmedicamentos.DataBind();

        }
        catch
        {
            lblerror.Text = "error";
        }
    }
    protected void drplistarfarma_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (drplistarfarma.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string nombre = drplistarfarma.SelectedValue;
                Medicamentos M = null;

                Gvmedicamentos.DataSource = Session["medi"];
                Gvmedicamentos.DataBind();

            }
            catch
            {
                lblerror.Text = "Error en grilla.";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ante el evento del dropdownlist quieres cargar un grid debes actuar en el evento de ese control, con lo cual seria el `SelectedIndexChanged` del combo.

Para que se ejecute el evento recuerda asignar la propiedad `AutoPostBack` en `true`, entonces el codigo quedaria:

```
protected void drplistarfarma_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (drplistarfarma.SelectedValue == null)
        return;

    try
    {
        string ruc = drplistarfarma.SelectedValue;

        var medi = LogicaMedicamento.ListarFarma(ruc);
        Gvmedicamentos.DataSource = medi;
        Gvmedicamentos.DataBind();

    }
    catch
    {
        lblerror.Text = "Error en grilla.";
    }
}
```

tomando la seleccion del combo la pasas como valor a la logica para que la use de filtro.

No veo porque instanciar la entidad `Medicamentos` si pasas un dato simple.

Comment: el proc pasa una Farmacia(que esta dentro de Medicamento)  por eso uso el medicamento, no me deja pasar el ruc asi, porque me dice que tiene que ser una "farmacia" , si miras el procedimiento anterior, los ruc los saco de la lista con ese formato, y si recorde poner el autopostback, solo llego a que me aparezcan los ruc en el Drop, pero selecciono uno y no me aparece la grilla, osea ni vacia ni completa, es como que nunca la hubiera creado

Comment: si al un GridView no le asignas datos nunca lo vas a visualizar salvo que definas el `EmptyDataTemplate ` con algun contenido, pude que este sucediendo eso, no ves el grid porque no hay nada que mostrar